# Java Scanner Dilimiter

Tags: java, regex, parsing, tokenize, delimiter

I'm using Scanner and a Delimiter to tokenize my .txt file (it's a homework that I've got to do). First version of the file looks like this:

```
5,5,5,6,5,8,9,5,6,8, good, very good, excellent, good
7,7,8,7,6,7,8,8,9,7,very good, Good, excellent, very good
8,7,6,7,8,7,5,6,8,7 ,GOOD, VERY GOOD, GOOD, AVERAGE
9,9,9,8,9,7,9,8,9,9 ,Excellent, very good, very good, excellent
7,8,8,7,8,7,8,9,6,8 ,very good, good, excellent, excellent
6,5,6,4,5,6,5,6,6,6 ,good, average, good, good
7,8,7,7,6,8,7,8,6,6 ,good, very good, good,  very good
5,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,7,7  ,excellent, very good, very good, very good
```

And I've used `useDelimiter("[ ]*(,)[ ]*")` second version of the file looks like this:

```
5 5 5 6 5 8 9 5 6 8 good, very good, excellent, good
7 7 8 7 6 7 8 8 9 7 very good, Good, excellent, very good
8 7 6 7 8 7  5 6 8 7 GOOD, VERY GOOD, GOOD, AVERAGE
9 9 9 8 9 7 9  8 9 9 Excellent, very good, very good, excellent
7 8 8 7 8 7 8 9 6 8 very good, good, excellent, excellent
6 5 6 4 5 6 5 6 6 6 good, average, good, good
7  8 7 7 6 8 7 8 6 6 good, very good, good,  very good
5 7 6 7 6 7 6 7 7 7  excellent, very good, very good, very good
```

And I can't come up with a regexp which would help me to separate numbers by space and words by comma. Esentially I need an array with 14 values (very good being a single variable)

Note there are multiple spaces (this is done on purpose to make it harder for us).

So any sort of help would be appreciated.

P.S. We're only allowed to use **Delimiters only** (no splits etc..)

Comment: There are 'space' (\s) and 'word' (\w) and 'digit' (\d) and 'word boundary' (\b) character classes for regex that might help you.

Comment: Do you want a comma between the final number and the first word?

Comment: I don't need to add anything to the file, I simply need to extract the values and put them into a multidimensional array in this case it would be int [8][14], the words will be replaced with appropriate numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, the key is the positive-lookbehind (`(<?=)`) and alternation (`|`):

```
String input = "9 9 9 8 9 7 9  8 9 9 Excellent, very good, very good, excellent";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("(?<=\\d)[\\s,]+|\\s*,\\s*");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Token: ." + s.next() + ".");
}
```

Prints:

```
Token: .9.
Token: .9.
Token: .9.
Token: .8.
Token: .9.
Token: .7.
Token: .9.
Token: .8.
Token: .9.
Token: .9.
Token: .Excellent.
Token: .very good.
Token: .very good.
Token: .excellent.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one `(((?<=[0-9]+)\s*(?=[0-9]+))|(,\s*(?=[a-zA-Z]+))|((?<=[0-9]+)\s*(?=[a-zA-Z]+)))`, looks awful but should work

Comment: Firstly, that is wrong. I guess you mean `(\s*,\s*)|(\s+)`. But that doesn't work either. It would separate `very good` into two tokens.

Comment: Numbers seem to be okay, but the strings only contain 1 letter each.

Comment: Works perfectly but if he ever asked me to explain it I wouldn't know where to start hehe :)

Comment: Indeed, so dies the | (alternation) works sort of like an "OR" condition?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `Scanner` allows you to change the delimiter at any time.  If you can rely on your input text always having 10 numbers at the beginning and 4 word groups at the end, then you can simply start with a delimiter that just splits on spaces (`\s+`) and after 10 calls to `nextInt()`, switch to a delimiter that splits on a 
comma and spaces (`\s*,\s*`).

Something like:

```
String input = "5 5 5 6 5 8 9 5 6 8 good, very good, excellent, good";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s+");
int[] results = new int[14];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    results[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
scanner.skip("\\s*");
for (int i = 10; i < 14; ++i) {
    String wordPhrase = scanner.next();
    int wordValue;
    if ("average".equalsIgnoreCase(wordPhrase))
        wordValue = 1;
    else if ("good".equalsIgnoreCase(wordPhrase))
        wordValue = 2;
    else if ("very good".equalsIgnoreCase(wordPhrase))
        wordValue = 3;
    else if ("excellent".equalsIgnoreCase(wordPhrase))
        wordValue = 4;
    else
        wordValue = 0;
    results[i] = wordValue;
}
```

It's also possible to do this with a single delimiter regex using [zero-width lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but this is probably a bit advanced for a simple homework problem.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, why didn't I thought of that before :) I've got an issue tho, 10th index always seems to be 0.

Comment: Ah whoops, I guess when you switch the delimiter, the `Scanner` doesn't consume the space(s) between the last number and the first word, so it gets something like "` good`" for the first word phrase.  I updated the answer to tell the `Scanner` to skip over spaces after changing the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] str = expression.split("(,\\s+)|(\\s+)");
```

Try this:

Comment: Again very good is split into separate tokens where it supposed to be a single one.